# How to display the length of each element of an array of object?

Tags: javascript

The JOURNAL array below contains 9 Objects. And each object contains an array. For instance, the first object contains an array with 3 elements that are "carrot", "exercise", "weekend". My goal is to write a code to display the length of each of array contained in each object.
Thanks for your input.

```js
var JOURNAL = [
  {"events1":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events2":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events3":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events4":["brussel sprouts","ice cream","brushed teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events5":["potatoes","candy","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events6":["brussel sprouts","pudding","brushed teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events7":["pizza","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events8":["bread","beer","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events9":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false}
];

for(let i = 0; i < JOURNAL.length; i++){
  let entry = JOURNAL[i];
  console.log(JOURNAL[i].length);
}
```

if my journal was the following below, I wouldn't have a problem

```js
  var JOURNAL = [
    {"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
    {"events":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
    {"events":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
    {"events":["brussel sprouts","ice cream","brushed teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
    {"events":["potatoes","candy","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
    {"events":["brussel sprouts","pudding","brushed teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
    {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
    {"events":["bread","beer","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
    {"events":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false}
  ];

  for(let i=0; i<JOURNAL.length; i++){
   let entry = JOURNAL[i];
   console.log(JOURNAL[i].events.length);
  }
```

Comment: Objects don't have a "length"

Comment: Do you mean the "length" of an object? (As pointy said, they don't have that, although you can figure it out depending on how you want to define "length".) Or the length of the arrays on `events1`, `events2`, etc.?

Comment: but if you do console.log(JOURNAL[0].events1.length) you get 3 for the first element.

Comment: Just FWIW, having the property name change in each object is generally poor practice. Instead, I'd just call the property `events`.

Comment: @Selfy - That's because `JOURNAL[0].events1` is an *array*. Arrays have a  defined `length` property. Objects in general don't. Could you please answer the questions above?

Comment: @JuChengJiang - When you post an answer, the question poster receives a notification. There's no need to nag them in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to achieve, but if you are looping through the array (`JOURNAL`) with a `for`-loop, you can access access the object with `JOURNAL[i]`. Then, you'll have an object like this:

```
{
  "events1": [
    "carrot",
    "exercise",
    "weekend"
  ],
  "squirrel":false
}
```

To then access the length of the array in `events1` you can just use `JOURNAL[i].events1.length`. If the number after the word `events` always increases by one and starts at `1`, you can do it like this:

```
JOURNAL[i]['events' + (i + 1)].length
```

```js
var JOURNAL = [
  {"events1":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events2":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events3":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events4":["brussel sprouts","ice cream","brushed teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events5":["potatoes","candy","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events6":["brussel sprouts","pudding","brushed teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events7":["pizza","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events8":["bread","beer","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events9":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false}
];

for(let i = 0; i < JOURNAL.length; i++) {
  let entry = JOURNAL[i];
  let number = i + 1;
  console.log(entry['events' + number].length);
}
console.log('---');

// or with for .. of
let counter = 0;
for (let entry of JOURNAL) {
  counter++;
  console.log(entry['events' + counter].length);
}
```

---

It's probably better to use a different data structure, where the key `events` is not increasing a value. Could you just do something like this?

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "events": [
    "carrot",
    "exercise",
    "weekend"
  ],
  "squirrel": false
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "events": [
    "bread",
    "pudding",
    "brushed teeth",
    "weekend",
    "touched tree"
  ],
  "squirrel":false
},
...
]
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: How would you write the same code with a for/of loop/

Comment: @Selfy I've added an example. With for/of, you don't have a counter, so you need to define one by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```js
var JOURNAL = [
  {"events1":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events2":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events3":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events4":["brussel sprouts","ice cream","brushed teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events5":["potatoes","candy","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events6":["brussel sprouts","pudding","brushed teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events7":["pizza","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events8":["bread","beer","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events9":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false}
];

for(let i = 0; i < JOURNAL.length; i++){
  let entry = JOURNAL[i];
  console.log(JOURNAL[i]["events" + (i + 1)].length);
}
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Object.entries()` function.

```
var JOURNAL = [
  {"events1":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events2":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events3":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events4":["brussel sprouts","ice cream","brushed teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events5":["potatoes","candy","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events6":["brussel sprouts","pudding","brushed teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events7":["pizza","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events8":["bread","beer","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events9":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false}
];
JOURNAL.map(item => {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            console.log(`{$key} length is ${value.length}.`);
        } 
    }
}
```

Official guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement that if the property names were consistent, you wouldn't have a problem, you could do as the first two answers suggest:

```
console.log(JOURNAL[i]["events" + (i + 1)].length);
```

The problem is, it's delicate. As soon as the name of the property isn't consistent with where it is in the array, it fails.

A more robust solution would be to find the property matching `eventsN` where `N` is any series of digits:

```
const prop = Object.keys(entry).find(key => /^events\d+$/.test(key));
console.log(prop ? entry[prop].length : -1); // Where -1 is "didn't find it"
```

Live Example:

```js
var JOURNAL = [
  {"events1":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events2":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events3":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events4":["brussel sprouts","ice cream","brushed teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events5":["potatoes","candy","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events6":["brussel sprouts","pudding","brushed teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events7":["pizza","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events8":["bread","beer","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events9":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false}
];

for(let i = 0; i < JOURNAL.length; i++){
  let entry = JOURNAL[i];
  const prop = Object.keys(entry).find(key => /^events\d+$/.test(key));
  console.log(prop ? entry[prop].length : -1); // Where -1 is "didn't find it"
}
```

---

Side note: If you like, you can use a `for-of` loop to loop through `JOURNAL`:

```
for (const entry of JOURNAL) {
  const prop = Object.keys(entry).find(key => /^events\d+$/.test(key));
  console.log(prop ? entry[prop].length : -1); // Where -1 is "didn't find it"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through the array and get the values and if it is array, check the length of it.

```
for(const elem of JOURNAL) {
 for(const val of Object.values(elem)){
    if(Array.isArray(val)){
        console.log('size - ', val.length);
    }
 }
```

}